# How to retrieve only the nodes from firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where users can create tasks for them to do throughout the day. Similar to a To-do list. I have a node in my firebase database called `"Tasks"` under this node is where all the tasks are added.

**Here is a visual example:**

[image]

I am of course able to add data to the firebase database. Here is the code for that:

```
taskTitle = titleTextField.text!
taskDescription = notesTextView.text

var tasks: [String: Any] = [:] // declaring empty dictionary

tasks["Description"] = taskDescription
tasks["Due Date"] = date_time

database.child("Tasks").child(taskTitle).setValue(tasks)
```

*SO IF THE USER CREATES A NEW TASK, LET'S SAY THER CREATE `"TASK 4"`, `"TASK 5"`, `"TASK 6"` IT WILL LOOK LIKE THIS:*

[image]

---

here is the jason data print:

```
    Tasks =     {
        "Task 1" =         {
            Description = Abcderf;
            "Due Date" = "Nov 17, 2021, 19:11";
        };
        "Task 2" =         {
            Description = Abcderf;
            "Due Date" = "Nov 17, 2021, 19:11";
        };
        "Task 3" =         {
            Description = Abcderf;
            "Due Date" = "Nov 17, 2021, 19:11";
        };
        "Task 4" =         {
            Description = Notes;
            "Due Date" = "";
        };
        "Task 5" =         {
            Description = Run;
            "Due Date" = "Nov 24, 2021, 12:11";
        };
        "Task 6" =         {
            Description = Run;
            "Due Date" = "Nov 24, 2021, 12:11";
        };
    };
}
```

Here is the code to print this snapshot:

```
var postRef: DatabaseReference? // declared outside of viewDidLoad()
var refHandle: DatabaseHandle? // declared outside of viewDidLoad()

//set the db ref
postRef = Database.database().reference()

//getting values from db
refHandle = postRef?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
    self.listOftasks.append("")
})
```

*I am just setting a breakpoint at `self.listoftasks.append("")`, and then in the console I am doing `"po snapshot"` which then prints the JSON object.*

---

### What do I need to do, to read only the name of the tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, if you only care about the tasks, you should load only the `Tasks` node instead of loading the entire database

```
tasksRef = Database.database().reference("Tasks")
```

---

Next up, you'll need to loop over the child nodes in your completion handler:

```
refHandle = tasksRef?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
    for taskSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(taskSnapshot.key)
    }
})
```

For this, I recommend also checking out some of the previous questions on [looping over child nodes in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bswift%5d%20loop%20children), such as:

---

Keep in mind: while the above only *prints* the keys of the tasks, it still retrieves the values of each node too. If you don't need the value in your code, consider keeping a separate node in your database with just the task names (and typically `true` values, since a path needs a value to exist) to reduce the bandwidth used.

---

Finally, having such sequential keys is a common anti-pattern in Firebase, so I recommend reading this classic post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I just stalked your developer story, and it's amazing. You're super smart and talented. Thanks again, boss.

Comment: I got it to work!